# REGEX: get all words in string that is not within a block quote

Tags: php, regex

Please take a look at this:

http://ideone.com/Mszb8z

```
$content = 'Hello I am Tom and I am <blockquote class="quotedText">another Tom inside a quote</blockquote>';

$pattern = '#Tom#';
$matches = array();
preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

This returns both `Tom` strings. But I only want `Tom` strings that are not inside block quote tags. In this case only one `Tom` string should be returned. How to do this?

Comment: Simple. Don't use a regex. Load the snippet into a DOM parser, delete all of the blockquotes elements and their children, then export the leftover text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
<blockquote[^>]*>[^<]*</blockquote>(*SKIP)(?!)|Tom
```

**Demo:**

```
<?php
$string = 'Hello I am Tom and I am <blockquote class="quotedText">another Tom inside a quote</blockquote>';
$regex="~<blockquote[^>]*>[^<]*</blockquote>(*SKIP)(?!)|Tom~";
$count = preg_match_all($regex,$string,$m);
echo $count."<br />";
print_r($m[0]);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
1 // means there is only one match
Array ( [0] => Tom )
```

**Explanation**

1. On the left side of the `|` alternation, we match a whole blockquote, which we know we don't want. The `(?!)` forces the regex to fail and backtrack when Tom is matched inside the blockquote. The engine backtracks to `(*SKIP)` which tells it to abandon the entire match so far and attempt a new match at the next position in the string.
2. On the right side of the alternation, we can now safely match Tom.

Thanks to Hamza for pointing out that instead of skipping blockquotes blocks that contain "Tom", we can just skip any blockquote block.

Comment: @TK123 Fixed typo, added explanation. Let me know if this works or if you have questions. :)

Comment: @TK123 Argh another typo. Fixed.

Comment: You could simplify the regex by matching/skipping all blockquotes `<blockquote[^>]*>.*?</blockquote\s*>(*SKIP)(?!)|Tom`

Comment: @tk123 Did this solve your problem, or are you still struggling with it? Let me know. :)